# tags in database, relational or NoSQL

Tags: optimization, nosql, relational-database

I have e following schema

PRODUCT(ID,Name,Description)
TAG(ID,Label)

Product will have about 1000000 records, Tag will have 100 records.
If I do it with relational database I'll make many-to-many relation
and in that table will be 10000000+ records, so I'm afraid it will be a bit slow.
I don't have any experience in NoSQL databases and was wandering will I have any benefits for making this schema in NoSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10,000,000 records are not *that* much, really. Especially in a table that primarily contains two INT fields (ProductId and TagId), where much, if not all of it, can be kept in RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2^24 = 16777216, so as long as you index the mapping table, a relational database will find the tags for a given product id in less than 24 steps of a simple binary tree search. It should not be slow at all.